# Subquery not using Index, even if forcing

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, execution-plan, mariadb-10.5

Using MariaDB 10.5.12 on CentOS 7
If it makes any difference, my "optimizer_use_condition_selectivity" = 1

If I run:

`EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ips WHERE ip="1.2.3.4"`

This query uses the index on the `ip` column (simple index).

However, if I run (simplest example query I could get):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT srl.id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ips WHERE ip=srl.ip) as ipcount
FROM srl
LIMIT 10
```

The subquery on the `ips` table doesn't have `ip` as `possible_keys`, it uses the `time` index (which isn't even used in the query!), and does a table scan (and this is a huge table).
If I put `FORCE INDEX(ip)`, the EXPLAIN says it uses the `ip` key, but it still does a table scan.

If I hardcode an IP, like:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT srl.id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ips WHERE ip="1.2.3.4") as ipcount
FROM srl
LIMIT 10
```

It uses the `ip` key as intended.

**What is preventing the subquery from using the index as supposed, in the `ip=srl.ip` example?**

ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 19537.7025,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "srl",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "r_loops": 1,
      "rows": 92181,
      "r_rows": 10,
      "r_table_time_ms": 0.055588922,
      "r_other_time_ms": 0.116198584,
      "filtered": 100,
      "r_filtered": 100
    },
    "subqueries": [
      {
        "expression_cache": {
          "r_loops": 10,
          "r_hit_ratio": 30,
          "query_block": {
            "select_id": 2,
            "r_loops": 7,
            "r_total_time_ms": 19537.40246,
            "table": {
              "table_name": "ips",
              "access_type": "index",
              "key": "time",
              "key_length": "4",
              "used_key_parts": ["time"],
              "r_loops": 7,
              "rows": 4948857,
              "r_rows": 5949193,
              "r_table_time_ms": 12379.15752,
              "r_other_time_ms": 7158.182676,
              "filtered": 100,
              "r_filtered": 1.656887e-4,
              "attached_condition": "convert(ips.ip using utf8mb4) = srl.ip",
              "using_index": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include [ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-formatjson-examples/) output for these queries?

Comment: @danblack Added now. Thanks!

Comment: I guess `attached_condition` tells me what it is! One is `utf8_general_ci`, the other is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, so MariaDB converts one of them, to match the collation. I didn't know about `ANALYZE` ! Great stuff! Thank you very much!

Comment: Charset problem.  Write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: yes. Also note MariaDB-10.5 has an [INET6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6/) data type. Needs IPv4 to be in a compat or mapped format (I should look up the difference).

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY? this is a lottery...

Comment: @Akina - my original query is much more complex than that and has ORDER BY. The above is just a minimal query to reproduce the problem. I simply kept the LIMIT so we don't think the table scan behavior is because there is no LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `attached_condition` in `ANALYZE` (added to the Question) tells me what it is! One is `utf8_general_ci`, the other is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, so MariaDB converts one of them, to match the charset.

Comment: and by implication, does not use the index because they are of a different character set and collation.